# Returning a value. The output always print 0

Tags: java, return

i'm learning how to return a value and try to write the following code;

```
public class JustTryingReturn {

static int a, b;
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
static int nganu() {
return a+b;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int c = nganu();
    System.out.println("Enter number ");
    a = sc.nextInt();
    b = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(c);
}

}
```

But the output always print 0 instead of `a+b`. What did i do wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the call

```
int c = nganu();
```

after you assign the input values of `a` and `b`. Otherwise they'll still contain `0` by default when you compute their sum.

```
System.out.println("Enter number ");
a = sc.nextInt();
b = sc.nextInt();
int c = nganu();
System.out.println(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call your function *after* you assign values to `a` and `b`. 
 So put this: `int c = nganu();` after you get `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this just change of order of this line:

```
 int c = nganu();
 a = sc.nextInt();
 b = sc.nextInt();
```

LIke this:

```
 public class JustTryingReturn {
  static    int a, b;

 static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 static  int nganu() {
 return a+b;
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  // the order was changed
   System.out.println("Enter number ");
    a = sc.nextInt();  
    b = sc.nextInt();   
   int c = nganu();
System.out.println(c);
 }  

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please change your code accordingly,**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //int c = nganu(); // here first time a,b is 0, still you haven't assign...
    System.out.println("Enter number ");
    a = sc.nextInt(); // now, actually you have assign value to a
    b = sc.nextInt(); // now, actually you have assign value to b
    int c = nganu();
    System.out.println(c);
}
```